# Result involving monic polynomial, its roots and the gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, gamma-function

Do you know any reference where this result is proved? We have already proved it but since we know that this is a known result, we want to omit the proof and cite a proper reference. Here you have a caption of the result, which involves the roots of a monic polynomial and the gamma function
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbT0D.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @Vinicius3141592 This is like a 5 line proof. Unless you can find it easily in the literature, just leave it in. If it is relatively well known, there's a good chance the reviewers will ask you to cite the proof and maybe give you a reference.